# Texture appearing IN front of other textures

Tags: texturing

[image: These leafs are appearing infront of the other leafs even though it is under them. While the others work fine.]
These leafs are appearing infront of the other leafs even though it is under them. While the others work fine.

Comment: have you enabled their In Front option (in the Object panel > Viewport Display)? have you tried a render?

Comment: Hi (nice theme btw), while we do see the issue, I think there isn't enough information to be able to give a precise answer without it being lucky guesses. I advise you to add more details, and even [share your file with us](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3051/53447) so that we can check what's going on.

Comment: @L0Lock i just imported it as a image as a plane but for some reason this image act different, was painted in photoshop

Comment: @Cyborg Primate As Lolock says please share your file, it's hard to guess what you've done in the original picture and hard to guess what you mean that it acts different   ;)